# Bootstrap Help- How to make one column go outside the container and take the rest of the page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am a beginner web developer, and have to finish a website project for a friend. All the content is being held inside the container div. I am using bootstrap, and needed some help with a feature he wanted. Basically, there is a section, that has two columns in it, where each is taking 50% of the page. The first column, I need the content to be held inside the container. The rest of the 50% of the rest of the page I want it to be taken up by a google maps. I have the map working, but if I make the row inside the container, the content on the left side of the page starts at the full width rather then being inside the container. I want the map to go outside its container and take the width of the rest of the page. How would I go on about doing this in bootstrap. Thank you for any help!

[Here is the exact image of what im trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2WQk.png)

Comment: Hello, can you show the current code?

Comment: Hello, here is a link to the codepen I uploaded. https://codepen.io/flame732/pen/Yzygoxx

Comment: You can check the answer below hope that addresses the problem you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you should do it

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
          <div class="">
            <p>Some Random Text 1</p>
            <p>Some Random Text 2</p>
            <p>Some Random Text 3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div id="map" style="height:400px; width:100%"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-water-jbu2l?file=/index.html)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If it helped please click the check mark to the left of answer so that the question can be considered as closed.

Comment: Playing around with it, I had a question. How would I make the content of the first column to be lined at the start of the container, as opposed to centered like it is? Ty in advanced

Comment: `justify-content-end` it's a flexbox property just change it `justify-content-start` and should do the trick. Read more about it here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/

Comment: Awesome awesome! Thanks so much for the help!